# Android - RecyclerView item not showing

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I want to make some items visible in the recyclerview view but not working... At first all RelativeLayouts are gone. When you do "setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)" only the "free" works.

```
            if(mac.getTur().equals("free")){
                holder.relativeFree.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  

            }else if(mac.getTur().equals("vip")){
                holder.relativeVip.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }else if(mac.getTur().equals("reklamKarsiligi")){
                holder.relativeReklam.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
```

**LOGCAT**

```
2020-01-13 00:31:57.694 31167-31167/com.maksu.iddaa D/Mac.getTur(): free
2020-01-13 00:31:57.745 31167-31167/com.maksu.iddaa D/Mac.getTur(): free
2020-01-13 00:31:57.798 31167-31167/com.maksu.iddaa D/Mac.getTur(): reklamKarsiligi
2020-01-13 00:31:57.833 31167-31167/com.maksu.iddaa D/Mac.getTur(): vip
2020-01-13 00:31:57.866 31167-31167/com.maksu.iddaa D/Mac.getTur(): vip
```

**MY SCREEN LOOKS LIKE THIS**

[image: RecyclerView]

Comment: Try, for each case, to hide other layouts before. Otherwise, can I see item xml file ?

Comment: I solved this problem. I've hidden the parents of relavitelayouts. Carelessness.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. I've hidden the parents of relavitelayouts. Carelessness.